# How to graphically symbolize quantity of items (vs weight)?

Tags: gui-design, mobile, icons

Im making something similar to a grocery store app. There is a field for the name of the product, and its quantity. Some products are naturally enumerated in weight (5 KG of cucumbers, 200 grams paprika) while others are naturally enumerated in quantity (3 pineapples, 2 bottles of milk).

Finding an icon for weight of an item is easy - you just use weights with "kg" on them:

[image]

I think I also have an idea for "grams". It's either a feather or the same set of weights but only with a small case "g".

But how do you create/find an icon for quantity of items? A "Q" is unsatisfactory (and anyway the early adopters will be non english speakers).

Comment: Fairly understandable and common symbol for count/amount is "#". https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_sign It CAN be mistaken for order/index in sequence, though.

Comment: The [pcs](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pcs) abbreviation could also be useful.

Comment: To add to @xpy, using abbreviations like kg, g and pcs, works for just about anything, including other languages because it's universal. Adding an icon to the mix would IMO dilute the communication because now the user is deciphering the non-standard icons you would be using for grams and pieces.

Answer (score 1):

Unless it is a widely used icon such as a shopping cart, only use icons as complementary, rather than as a substitute. A rule of thumb I like to employ is if it hard to think of a suitable icon then it's usually best to avoid icons.

Find a layout your target market is familiar with, such as a local receipt. If they're not used to supermarket receipts look at how information is displayed at their local market.

Once the layout works without icons, you can try bringing them in as complimentary.

If it is a web app, be aware of translation tools and ensure that abbreviations can be translated, e.g. 'Kg' or 'Kilogram', and that text within an image cannot be translated.

Finally, you mentioned bottles of milk being measured in quantity, these could also have sizes. Ensure you're design caters for quantity as well as size especially if the person cannot see and touch the item.
e.g. 2x 200ml Milk

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to display an alphabet like Q for quantity. You can try the shopping bag symbol. And if you can dynamically change the count on the shopping bag based on the number of items added then that would be very good. You can also try a simple Plus (+) icon over a shopping bag icon

For reference check few icons on the following link:
https://thenounproject.com/imicons/collection/shopping-and-e-commerce/?i=69912